# Strange Java variable binding behavior

Tags: java, python, binding, closures, tdd

I have the following class

```java
public class Envirionment {

    private Square[][] grid;

    public Envirionment(int width, int height) {
        this.grid = new Square[height][width];
    }

    public void map(SquareActor actor) {
        for(int y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {
                actor.act(grid[y][x]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

In order to test that the `map` method was working correctly, I started building a test, the goal of the test was to pass in a function which can act upon the squares, and see if it's working correctly.

One of the main parts of this test is ensuring it's actually looping through all of the squares, so I thought I could pass in a function, which could bind to the `x` and `y` variables of the loop, and call a callback function with the values of `x` and `y`, and keep a local counter in the test to compare and contrast.

I started off by testing to see if I could pass in a function that would just print out the `x` and `y` variables but I hit my first hurdle.

```java
class EnvirionmentTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        Envirionment env = new Envirionment(10, 10);
        env.map((square) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", x, y)));
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Turns out that the compiler started yelling at my because `x` and `y` cannot be resolved to a variable, however I thought these would bind to the scope of the loops they would be called within.

Is it possible to set the binding for these variables in java? Or am I approaching this problem completely wrong?

---

edit:

I just tried something similar in python, and it seemed to work fine.

```py
test = lambda : print(str(x) + "," str(y))
for y in range(2):
    for x in range(2):
        test()
```

output:

```
0,0
1,0
0,1
1,1
```

Comment: `env.map((square) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", square.x, square.y)));` ?

Comment: Nope, the squares don't know anything about their position.

Comment: Then they can't pass out those variables, can they?

Comment: Exactly why I wanted to use the x and y variables within the loop scopes :)

Comment: You're not passing X and Y to the method.  What you're trying is nonsensical.

Comment: ... You aren't understanding what I am trying to do, see the python example above...

Comment: This isn't Python, it's Java.  You cannot access local variables in Java like that.

Comment: Okay, why not? The point of the question is to either get a solution to this binding problem (maybe there is some java specific behavior I don't know about), or explain why variable binding doesn't/cannot work this way in java. Not for someone to confirm that python isn't java...

Comment: Also passing in x and y to this function would be bad design as it means I would have to change the arguments to a function for the sake of testing. Your code should never be forced to change to become more testable, if you are in a situation like that then you are doomed to exposing things you really shouldn't be and breaking encapsulation.

Comment: does the python example also work if `test` is defined in another function (then `x` and `y`), like you are doing in Java? doesn't matter much since there is no reason for Java be the same as Pyhon, but just to confirm

Comment: Yes, so `test = lambda : lambda : print(str(x))` then run that through a for loop (`for x in range(10)` for example and run `test()()` in the args and you will see the `x` bind to the for loops `x`. It's basically the lambda calculus equivalent of `(\z.(\y.x))` and then doing a eta abstraction `(\x.(\z.(\y.x)))` which then captures `x`.

Comment: Although that's not what I'm doing in java, in java I'm passing a function with unbound variables `(\z.xz)` to another function `(\x.xx)` which should be captured like this: `(\x.xx)(\z.xz) ->b (\x.(\z.xz)(\z.xz))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your python example you create lambda expression which would have equivalent in Java like :

```
BiConsumer<String, String> biFunction = (x, y) -> System.out.println(x + "," + y);
```

In your example you receive compilation error because in this expression :

```
env.map((square) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", x, y)));
```

compiler does not know what `x` and `y` is and he is right.

Your `Environment::map` method takes argument of type `SquareActor`. You are passing lambda expression to `Environment::map` which will be resolved as instance of anonymous class implementing `SquareActor` which has to be a `FunctionalInterface`. In your case your lambda expression would have to look like

```
env.map((square, x, y) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", x, y)));
```

but then it would not match `SquareActor::act` method signature. Java does not support closures which you think. If you want to know how to implement closures in Java check [this article](https://medium.com/@rmanavalan/5-ways-to-implement-closures-in-java-8-590790659ac5).

Your `Environment::map` method just loops through internal array and passes arguments to `SquareActor::act`. So you should not have access to local loop counters inside `SquareActor::act` dont you think? If you want to test your method you just want to check if your "mock" implementation will be fired as many times as it should be so :

```
env.map(square -> System.out.println(String.format("Square " + square)));
```

should be enough (if you override the `toString` method for `Square` class.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the BiConsumer lambda you've shown is the same as the python example, mainly because for python to do something similar it would look like this:

Comment: test = lambda x, y: print(str(x) + "," str(y))

Comment: The above example I gave was a closure where as this is a complete function. The reason why I didn't want to pass in a complete function was because I didn't want to alter the interface that the `act` method was expecting. (I didn't want to force them to use the x and y when they may only need to square).

Comment: Which example are you talking about? I cannot see any closure there. Where do you call a function that returns a function?

Comment: A closure isn't just a function that returns a function. A closure is a way of dealing with bindings. If you have a function `(\z.xz)` and pass that function into `(\x.xx)` you get `(\x.xx)(\z.xz) ->b (\x.(\z.xz)(\z.xz))` where the inner most `x` is now bound to the outer scope. That's a closure....So the above closure example would be `(square) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", x, y))` which is being passed into the `act` function and binding to the `x` and `y` arguments.

Comment: Another example of a closure would be the python example I gave

Answer (score 1):

In the Square class, you could define these x and y values as local variables, and then use the lambda function like this:

```
  env.map((square) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", square.x, square.y)));
```

Comment: This breaks cohesion, the purpose of the Environment class is to store squares and manage their positions and the purpose of the square class is to act as a container. A square need not know about where it is at any given time.

Comment: You could use something like env.getSquarePosition(square) instead. Maybe env has to be declared final then

Comment: All of this is missing the point. You should never have to change the interface of an object in order to test said object. You shouldn't have to break encapsulation or cohesion in order to test an object. You can test this method as it is in other languages, python, javascript, and php, I was wondering if there was a way of doing this binding manipulation in java, but apparently there isn't.

Comment: Last idea that comes to mind is to change the act-Method's Parameters to Square , int, int  and then pass them: actor.act(grid[y,x], x,y). Of course you would have to call the lambda function with (square, x,y) -> then of course. I don't think it's possible to do it the way you want in java.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. Feels horrible though.